# Still getting those SMS and CALL_LOG warning in Google Play console, when my app DOESNT use these permissions?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, google-play-console

I got this message sometimes above my app in the Dashboard menu. Sometimes it is here, sometimes it is not. What the heck is going on here, my app uses the following permissions:

`ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`

`INTERNET`

Also, I double checked it:

- when I install app on phone, and check on phone => apps => permissions, there are none other permission except those listed above

So I am pretty much 100% sure I dont use these permissions, but I still see the warning. Why? It simply must be a bug or something... ? i want to contact google play support please give me a direct link to the issue, or another solution, i also make new update with those changes below

```html
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"
tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"
tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"
tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"
tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH"
tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS"
tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"
tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG"
tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"
tools:node="remove" />
```

Comment: Is you use any 3rd party lib or module in your project?

Comment: "i want to contact google play support" - well do that then, instead of posting a complaint here

Comment: shane - im not using any third part lib or modul in my projet

Comment: Tim Castelijns - i mean direct link to this issue, when you try to contact google support there are a bunch of steps and categories, and thank you

Comment: You have to check your "merged manifest" in order to be sure you have not this permission set up. Take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#inspect_the_merged_manifest_and_find_conflicts) for reference.

Comment: @shadowsheep  good idea, Thank you

Comment: after using apkanalyzer i find those permission---------------------------------------- ( <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />  ) 
          -----------------------------------------------------------------and another permission inside a service section  ( android:permission="android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE" >  )

Comment: With android studio open up your `AndroidManifest.xml` and on the bottom tab click on "Merged Manifest" you should see here which lib put this permission.

Comment: @shadowsheep that is very helpful.

Comment: Glad to know. Hope you'll find the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

For that, I had just looked into **Release management -> Artifact library-> Active artifacts**, it was showing me an older active version(which have permissions of SMS) in the alpha version then after I had just uploaded new latest APK file(without SMS/Call permissions) in alpha version.

Finally, they removed warning from my console.
So, Firstly you have to check out that there is no other old alpha/beta versions are in active mode. I hope it will resolve your issue.